# difference between 2 methods of form submissions

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two form submission methods?

```
<form method="post" action="gert.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <p>Enter an email address:</p>
    <input id='email'>
    <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="gert.php" onSubmit='validate(); return false;'>
    <p>Enter an email address:</p>
    <input id='email'>
    <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
</form>
```

I'm using the first one in submitting forms and returning `false` in the JavaScript `validate()` function if the form is not filled out. Just now in another website, I have seen the second one being used. I am unable to figure out the difference, so I want to know if I'm using still old ways in doing the things or if both mean the same thing? I was thinking in the second way, form will be submitted only if `thisform.submit` statement is executed. I came to know this when I executed the form but I still want to know what is the major difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example will only ever be submitted if the response from `validate()` is *truthy*.

The second example will validate the form (call `validate()`) but it will never be submitted, as a *falsy* value is sent back to the event handler function will cancel the default browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, if `validate()` returns `true`, then you form will be submitted.
The second one, no matter what `validate()` returns, the form will not be submitted.(But the form can be submitted in `validate` function.)